# PHPUnit: mocking the function

Tags: php, tdd, phpunit

Is it possible to create a mock for the function?

**UPD1**:

```
$class->callback('callback_function');
```

I've tried to test whether `callback_function` was invoked once or not.

Answer (score 3):

Native functions cannot be mocked. You would need something like [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) or [patchwork](http://antecedent.github.io/patchwork) to do so.

What you could do though, is utilize a [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) and wrap the native function calls into separate Command Objects or Closures/Lambdas and use those instead. Those can be passed around and exchanged freely.

Example 1 - Using a Lambda Function:

```
$callback = function() { 
    // a native function in here
}
$class->callback($callback);
```

Example 2 - Using a Command Object:

```
interface ICommand
{ 
    public function execute();
}
class Callback implements ICommand
{
    public function execute()
    { 
        // a native function in here
    }
}
$class->callback(array('Callback', 'execute'));
```

You can then mock those callbacks easily. I am not sure how PHPUnit implements the 'I have been called' thing. Either look into the sourcecode or add a subject/observer pattern.

Comment: I've tried to cover callback invocation with unit test case, so strategy pattern is not suitable here. But thanks for opinion, +1

Comment: @zerkms actually I don't see why it shouldnt be suitable. Just exchange the callback with a lambda or a command object that mocks the original callback. Maybe you can update the question to show what you are trying to test.

Comment: Yep, but case 1 is not mock - i cannot specify with some declaration number of its callings. In second case - we will call method, **BUT** inside `callback()` implementation method and function are being invoked in slightly different manner, so we should test both.

Comment: $mock->expects($this->once())->method('unit_test_callback') -- this is how phpunit accepts "number-of-calls" behaviour

Comment: @zerkms A Mock substititutes for a dependency. PHPUnit does provide a convenient method for creating Mocks with certain functionality, but you can very much use your own, including that from Ex1 (yes, you cannot use that with `->expect()` then, but it's still a Mock). I do not know what you mean by *we should test both* for Ex2 as I do not know your implementation. The whole point of the examples is to illustrate how to wrap native functions in object callbacks or lambdas so they become mockable.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... The issue is "how to pass function which will be mock", by saying this i mean - function, that acts with pre-set behaviour: expects specific parameters, returns specific value and being called only once. i can construct such mock-object, but for function it seems like there is no elegant solution.

Comment: @zerkms Well, that's the most elegant solution I can offer. Pass in a [callback](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) and it's arguments. Call it with [`call_user_func_array`](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Yes, you have to replace ALL function calls you want to mock - or use runkit.

Comment: I do know what `callback` and `call_user_func_array` are. I do know how to invoke function. The issue is **how to test that function was invoked just once**. It is PHPUnit-specific question, not the question about some general php programming practices.

Comment: @zerkms I understood that it is about PHPUnit specifically, but like Alex and I already told you: *functions* cannot be mocked with PHPUnit. I suggested to use your own Mock in that case. If that's not what you want, ok. Also, if this is specifically about `$mock->expects($this->once())->method('unit_test_callback')`, then you should change your question to reflect this and add what you expect 'unit_test_callback' to be if it is not a method in the mock. If it is a method in the mock, you can use the Strategy Pattern. And that's where it goes in circles.

Comment: i'm confused.. but anyway - it is not possible to make "clean" mock for function without any additional code, due to php ideology. that's what i had to know ;-) thanks for the replies, and sorry if i was rude :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you have Runkit installed, this library can also work and gives you the same fluent interface as PHPUnit's mock framework:

https://github.com/tcz/phpunit-mockfunction